# Need to get the actual Ip address in vaadin 8.8.5

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I am trying to get the actual ip address in the vaadin version 8.8.5

below is the code I am using

```
VaadinRequest.getCurrent().getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
```

but getting null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X-Forwarded-For` is only added if there's a "well behaving" proxy or such in between. Absence of `X-Forwarded-For` either means that there isn't any proxy, or that there is a proxy that doesn't follow the general convention of adding that header.

In the case of no proxy, then you can get the IP directly from the request as `VaadinRequest.getCurrent().getRemoteAddr()`.

In the case of a proxy that doesn't add the header, then there is unfortunately no way of finding the actual IP address. `getRemoteAddr()` will in that case give the IP address of the proxy instead, and you don't have any good way of knowing whether the IP is for a proxy or a real user.

Comment: Hi @Leif Astrand I tried this already and It gives me local address 127.0.0.1 but I need real ip address.I want this type of real ip address but with vaadin you can check https://ipapi.co/

Comment: When you are developing locally, then the server will only see you localhost address since that's the route through which you local browser connects to your local server. Once the application is deployed on some other network, then you will see an ip address related to that network. The browser does not, for security reasons, expose any other IP addresses to the web server than the one through which it actually accesses the server.